# Active class in pagination in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've made a pagination, everything works, but I don't know how to set active class on single page.

This is my example:

Pagination code:

```
    const renderPagination = numbers.map(number => {
        return (
            <li className="controls" key={number} id={number} onClick={this.handlePages}>
                {number}
            </li>
        );
    });
```

Full example:

[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qKdamV)

Comment: Do you mean on the buttons of the page switching element? Like highlight the button "2" when on page 2?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I mean.

Comment: @neil, you specifically got an error that you need to include your code in the post. Trying to circumvent that requirement by marking some random text as code isn't cool. Please insert your code to your post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<li className={(this.state.currentPage === number ? 'active ' : '') + 'controls'} key={number} id={number} onClick={this.handlePages}>
  {number}
</li>
```

You can add class when state equal number

https://codepen.io/titan_dl_1904/pen/XYbjye

Answer (score 1):

Since the `currentPage` is in the state you can grab it from there and compare it to the `number` of the page link you are displaying

```
    const renderPagination = numbers.map(number => {
        var activeClass = this.state.currentPage === number ? 'active' : '';
        return (
            <li className={`controls ${activeClass}`} key={number} id={number} onClick={this.handlePages}>
                {number}
            </li>
        );
    });
```

Updated demo (*with some styling too*): https://codepen.io/gpetrioli/pen/MXwbYv